# Returning smallest item in a list in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

Note: I am doing this for homework. I'm not looking for the algorithm to solve my problem, just trying to understand how Scheme works.

I'm new to scheme and trying to write a small program to find the smallest item in a list. The program is working in the since that it is finding the correct answer (so the logic is somewhat sound), but I only know this because an error is coming up that it's trying to treat my answer as a function and call it.

```
(DEFINE (startmin mylist)
(

    (repeatmin (CAR mylist) (CDR mylist))


))


(DEFINE (repeatmin curmin mylist)
(

    (IF (NULL? mylist) ;If the list is empty

        ;This is where I'm at a loss. I want a way for this value to be
        ;sent out once the list is empty
        curmin ;return the current minimum

        (IF (< curmin (CAR mylist)) ;if the current minimum is less than the head of the list
            (repeatmin curmin (CDR mylist)) ;recurse with curmin
            (repeatmin (CAR mylist) (CDR mylist)) ;otherwise recurse with the head of the list.
        )
    )
))
```

I'm really at a loss of how I get the value, once found, back out of the recursion as it keeps trying to treat the value as a function.

Comment: [Sylwester's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43430528/7872323) fixed it for me.

Comment: You shouldn't mark your question as "[solved]" manually. Accept Sylwester's answer by clicking its grey check mark symbol, and the question's miniatures will be marked green automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parentheses are off. If you write

```
((if ...))
```

it means that the result from `if` is a function that immediately should be called once the value is cmoputed. It seems like you are using parentheses as if they are blocks, like `{}` in C, but they are not. In fact `(begin ...)` is a block in Scheme. And of course a function, `let` and `cond` terms have implicit begin.. Thus

```
(define (func . args)
  (begin 
    x
    y))
```

Is the same as

```
(define (func . args)
  x
  y)
```

Also please [format your code correctly](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style). Indentation helps you read the code and the nesting. I really don't pay attention to the parentheses, just the position which is crucial. Choose an editor that does this for you. Eg. [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) is a nice one I use.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the extra set of Parentheses that was throwing it off. I guess I kinda missunderstood when the teacher was explaining how the Parens where used in class, I took them to be the same as both Parens and Curly Braces from C. I'll go through that style guide and get my code into a better format now. 

Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristopherMayer You're welcome. I think knowing other languages makes it harder to learn Scheme, but it's a great language and you might become better in the other languages you know as well since you learn to think differently. If this answer helped you please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).